# contenteditable divs has a weird behaviour on focus in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I decided to use div with contenteditable instead of input. Here is a code, it's simple `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` So, and look at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkfKk/

Just for jsfiddle I've marked an area of first line. In Opera, I must click directly to marked area to focus the div. Also, I can focus by double click in any space over there. But, that click shouldn't be double. I hope I explain it right. In Chrome and any other browser, I can make just one click to any place in div to focus it. On marked area or on non-marked area, whatever. That's correct behaviour, I believe.

Comment: +1 for the well presented fiddle. Though, the easiest solution would be to just not test in Opera. It has barely 1-2% market share and its users are mostly hipsters that want to get broken pages *shrug* `</rant>`. No but really, as Opera is just transitioning to Blink, I'd expect all kinds of weird bugs in the next months.

Comment: The reason why double click works is because double click means select all. Try typing some words and double click in the remaining space of the div to test this out. I would say this is a browser implementation issue and there is little we can do about it.

Comment: @Antony, yes, thank you. By the way, that selection misses a symbols like «',\*(» and similar. That's interesting but cannot help.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, you're probably right. Opera 14 on Webkit is coming soon. But anyway I should show the job to client now and I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. That solution has some defects but that's enough for me. When I click on non-marked area focus-event triggers anyway. So, I decided just set cursor position to the last possible position on trigger focus-event. Here's code:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var selection = getSelection();
var children = this.childNodes;
var last = children[children.length-1];
if (last.textContent.length) {
    range.setStart(last,last.textContent.length);
} else {
    range.setStart(this,0);
}
range.collapse(true);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

And this binds on `focus`, that's all. The solution is easy indeed but that works well.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkfKk/7/